# Why does the licensing documentation not correspond to my Eclipse development environment?

Tags: android

I am trying to incorporate the Google Play Licensing service into my project. I am using Windows 7 and Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2. My SDK is installed at c:\android-sdk-windows under which I have an extras directory, a google-market_licensing directory and a market_licensing directory.

Under the extras directory, I have a google directory but it does not contain a market_licensing directory - as expected by the documentation.

Am I anywhere near the right pew or in the totally wrong church?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your imagination: the documentation is out of date. In the Android SDK Manager, point 'Google Market Licensing' with your mouse and you will get a tooltip with the current install location (Hint: it's `$SDK_HOME/google_market_licensing`).

Comment: That's my point: I have 'Google Play Licensing Library' and also an entry for 'Market Licensing'! So which is it?

Comment: Clear the SDK manager cache and try again. Market=>Google Play, so it is the newer one. Contents is the same.

Comment: Found it. No differrence ... I'm plodding my way through this but for something that's supposedly so simple, it's quickly approaching the complexity of an app by itself. Thanks for your help though ...